# SQL Server: Primary Key Conflict

Tags: sql, sql-server, key

First of all I want to apologize for the messy code you are about to experience but it is important for my point. I have simplified it down somewhat but here is generally the code that I am working with:

```
create table [TableExample](
    ID varchar(50) primary key not null,
);

with CTE as (
    select case when ltrim(rtrim(S1.ID)) is null
            then convert(varchar(50),newid())
            else ltrim(rtrim(S1.ID))
        end as 'ID',
    row_number()over(partition by ltrim(rtrim(S1.ID)) order by newid()) as 'duplicates' 
    from [DB2].[dbo].[Source1] as S1
    full outer join [DB2].[dbo].[Source2] as S2
        on S2.[ID]=S1.[ID]
    full outer join [DB2].[dbo].[Source3] as S3
        on S3.[ID]=S1.[ID])

insert into [dbo].[TableExample] (
    [ID]
)

select  distinct case 
        when [duplicates] > 1
            then convert(varchar(50),newid())
            else CTE.[ID]
        end as 'ID'
from [DB2].[dbo].[Source1] as S1
full outer join [DB2].[dbo].[Source2] as S2
    on ltrim(rtrim(S2.ID))=ltrim(rtrim(S1.ID))
full outer join [DB2].[dbo].[Source3] as S3
    on ltrim(rtrim(S3.ID))=ltrim(rtrim(S1.ID))
full outer join CTE on CTE.ID=ltrim(rtrim(S1.ID))
where (S2.ID is not null or S3.ID is not null or S1.ID is not null)
    and [duplicates] = 1
```

As you can see I am running multiple very redundant checks to make sure that the primary key field [ID] does not receive any duplicates. I select distinct, use CTE to mark any duplicate keys then refuse them, and finally if any still get through I have duplicates changed to

```
convert(varchar(50),newid())
```

And yet, every time I run this I hit a duplicate key error.

If you're wondering, yes I do drop the table each time just to make sure nothing is preserved that could be causing the error.

There are more than 100,000 lines of data that need to be entered and I am at my wit's end with this thing. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide sample data for tables Source1, Source2, and Source3, and an explanation of what duplicates you're looking for? The confusing part is, in the CTE, Source2 and Source3 are joined, but they aren't used. Are the duplicates spread out among those tables? You might need unions instead of joins.

Comment: The error message identifies a duplicate value. So remove the insert statement and just run the select query for the ID value mentioned. And your logic is dense and, as written, makes little sense. Are you assuming that ID is unique in each table? The repetition of the full join in both CTE and the actual select statement is difficult to understand - made worse by the inconsistent join logic. Rarely does one need to trim strings for joining, but if you do then why do you **not** trim in the cte?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to union the IDs from Source1, Source2, and Source3, trim them, and look for duplicates. If there are duplicate rows, leave one as is, and replace the others with new uniqueidentifers. This accomplishes exactly that:

```
CREATE TABLE TableExample ( ID VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL)
CREATE TABLE Source1 ( ID VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL)
CREATE TABLE Source2 ( ID VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL)
CREATE TABLE Source3 ( ID VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO Source1 VALUES ('6C0240E7-847B-41F3-9DCA-D2EA54FB0E96'), (' 6C0240E7-847B-41F3-9DCA-D2EA54FB0E96 '), ('007171B1-10DB-4DD2-832F-026C968AC19A'), ('A28976BC-443F-44E6-9AED-B41DAFBBB651')
INSERT INTO Source2 VALUES ('6C0240E7-847B-41F3-9DCA-D2EA54FB0E96 '), ('007171B1-10DB-4DD2-832F-026C968AC19A'), ('80373FA7-5A61-41AB-B7DA-1F807A0E442B'), ('A38C6C43-A2B1-4C5B-8699-601054FB7968')
INSERT INTO Source3 VALUES ('  6C0240E7-847B-41F3-9DCA-D2EA54FB0E96 '), ('1A366E5C-0B6C-4B3D-B3E4-126035D641F1'), ('1183D160-AF00-43C1-8EA1-E953B51918E4'), (' 80373FA7-5A61-41AB-B7DA-1F807A0E442B ')

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(ID)) ID
    FROM Source1 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(ID)) ID
    FROM Source2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(ID)) ID
    FROM Source3
),
CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY NEWID()) AS RN
    FROM CTE
)
INSERT INTO TableExample (ID)
SELECT CASE WHEN RN > 1 THEN CAST(NEWID() AS VARCHAR(50)) ELSE ID END AS ID
FROM CTE2

SELECT * FROM TableExample
```

Outputs:

```
ID
007171B1-10DB-4DD2-832F-026C968AC19A
0841CEF6-B70E-442F-90CD-B79C235107F9
0AE6C8EC-31CF-49EA-B992-09E0CDC32B61
1183D160-AF00-43C1-8EA1-E953B51918E4
16EE8FD4-E5C9-480E-98DB-1410DCB0CFF5
1A366E5C-0B6C-4B3D-B3E4-126035D641F1
2C5F8AE0-CE70-406C-96C4-FE5144C16634
6C0240E7-847B-41F3-9DCA-D2EA54FB0E96
80373FA7-5A61-41AB-B7DA-1F807A0E442B
A28976BC-443F-44E6-9AED-B41DAFBBB651
A38C6C43-A2B1-4C5B-8699-601054FB7968
CB426799-E85E-4D13-AC6A-16ACC571333A
```

Comment: I am trying out a variation of this suggestion. The code I provided was obviously a bit too simplified. There are other fields than just ID and they are different from each source, so it does need to be a join and not a union. That being said even with that change it looks a lot cleaner than what I had before. I'll post again with the results.

Comment: Yes! The modified code worked wonderfully thank you. I have upvoted your comment but it didn't appear publicly due to the <15 rep thing, and marked the question as answered.